# How to convert this apache rewrite into nginx correctly?

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx

How to rewrite this Apache rule on Nginx?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*(pdf|epub)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-content/themes/divi-child/download.php?file=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apache mod_rewrite rule you specified redirects requests for files ending with the suffix pdf or epub to `/wp-content/themes/divi-child/download.php?file=`, with the filename appended to the end of the URI.

Using nginx, this could be accomplished with the following location block within your virtual host configuration:

`location ~* \.(pdf|epub)$ {
   rewrite ^/(.*(?:pdf|epub))$ /wp-content/themes/divi-child/download.php?file=$1;
}`

This [Stack Overflow question](https://serverfault.com/questions/185244/nginx-location-try-files-rewrite-find-pattern-match-in-subfolder-else-move) offers a bit of insight into how the pattern matching works for file extensions.

For more information, check out the [nginx documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location) and [blog posts](https://www.nginx.com/blog/converting-apache-to-nginx-rewrite-rules/).

Comment: Thanks for yor answer Chris. This example works for me, and for some reason yours does not:

`location ~* \.(pdf|epub)$ {
  rewrite ^/(.*(?:pdf|epub))$ /wp-content/themes/divi-child/download.php?file=$1;
}`

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the working location block you have confirmed as working.